# Creating and Capturing payment with paypal v2 node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate PayPal server-side payment on a website with a new v2 since v1 is deprecated. Since I had to include quite a lot of code from their git, i will post here everything for a working example

In v1 i could do it really easily:

```
app.get('/create', function (req, res) {
    //build PayPal payment request
    let payReq = JSON.stringify({
        'intent': 'sale',
        'redirect_urls': {
            'return_url': 'http://localhost:8081/process',
            'cancel_url': 'http://localhost:8081/cancel'
        },
        'payer': {
            'payment_method': 'paypal'
        },
        'transactions': [{
            'amount': {
                'total': '7.47',
                'currency': 'USD'
            },
            'description': 'This is the payment transaction description.'
        }]
    });

    paypal.payment.create(payReq, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            //capture HATEOAS links
            let links = {};
            payment.links.forEach(function (linkObj) {
                links[linkObj.rel] = {
                    'href': linkObj.href,
                    'method': linkObj.method
                };
            })

            //if redirect url present, redirect user
            if (links.hasOwnProperty('approval_url')) {
                res.redirect(links['approval_url'].href);
            } else {
                console.error('no redirect URI present');
            }
        }
    });
});


app.get('/process', function (req, res) {
    let paymentId = req.query.paymentId;
    let payerId = {'payer_id': req.query.PayerID};

    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, payerId, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            if (payment.state == 'approved') {
                const payerCountry = payment.payer.payer_info.country_code;
                const total = payment.transactions[0].amount.total;
                const currency = payment.transactions[0].amount.currency;

                savePayment(payerCountry, total, currency);

                res.send('payment completed successfully ' + cnt++);
            } else {
                res.send('payment not successful');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The `create` endpoint basically creates the order, the paypal API returns hateos links and the controller says the browser should redirect to that link. Once redirected , if user approves payment on paypal site he is redirected to on of

```
'redirect_urls': {
    'return_url': 'http://localhost:8081/process',
    'cancel_url': 'http://localhost:8081/cancel'
},
```

`process` endpoints retrieves `PAYMENT ID` and `PAYER ID` from query and captures the order - allowing me to do whatever i want to do ( e.g save payment in db ) in callback.

Now `v2` seems like huge mess:

Following devs  [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) i have created

Paypal button (copy paste ):

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {PayPalButtons, PayPalScriptProvider, usePayPalScriptReducer} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

// This values are the props in the UI
const amount = "2";
const currency = "USD";
const style = {"layout": "vertical"};
    const ButtonWrapper = ({currency, showSpinner}) => {
        // usePayPalScriptReducer can be use only inside children of PayPalScriptProviders
        // This is the main reason to wrap the PayPalButtons in a new component
        const [{options, isPending}, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: "resetOptions",
                value: {
                    ...options,
                    currency: currency,
                },
            });
        }, [currency, showSpinner]);
    
        const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
            console.log("create")
            return fetch('http://localhost:8081/create', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function (orderData) {
                console.log(orderData);
                window.location = orderData.redirect;
            });
        }
    
        // Call your server to finalize the transaction
        const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
            console.log("approve")
            return fetch('/process', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function (orderData) {
                // Three cases to handle:
                //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you
    
                // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
                // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
                var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
    
                if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                    return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
                    // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                }
    
                if (errorDetail) {
                    var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                    if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                    if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                    return alert(msg); // Show a failure message (try to avoid alerts in production environments)
                }
    
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction ' + transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');
            });
        }
    
    
        return (<>
                {(showSpinner && isPending) && <div className="spinner"/>}
                <PayPalButtons
                    style={style}
                    disabled={false}
                    forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
                    fundingSource={undefined}
                    createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)}
                    onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)}
                />
            </>
        );
    }


export default function PayPalButton() {
    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "750px", minHeight: "200px" }}>
            <PayPalScriptProvider
                options={{
                    "client-id": "test",
                    components: "buttons",
                    currency: "USD"
                }}
            >
                <ButtonWrapper
                    currency={currency}
                    showSpinner={false}
                />
            </PayPalScriptProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And then followed the flow from paypal's github [example](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK/blob/master/samples/CaptureIntentExamples/runAll.js)

created their HttpClient

```
const checkoutNodeJssdk = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

/**
 * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment which has access
 * credentials context. This can be used invoke PayPal API's provided the
 * credentials have the access to do so.
 */
function client() {
    return new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment());
}

/**
 * Setting up and Returns PayPal SDK environment with PayPal Access credentials.
 * For demo purpose, we are using SandboxEnvironment. In production this will be
 * LiveEnvironment.
 */
function environment() {
    let clientId = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || '<clientId>';
    let clientSecret = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET || '<secret>';

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        return new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.LiveEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
    }

    return new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
}

async function prettyPrint(jsonData, pre=""){
    let pretty = "";
    function capitalize(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    for (let key in jsonData){
        if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if (isNaN(key))
                pretty += pre + capitalize(key) + ": ";
            else
                pretty += pre + (parseInt(key) + 1) + ": ";
            if (typeof jsonData[key] === "object"){
                pretty += "\n";
                pretty += await prettyPrint(jsonData[key], pre + "\t");
            }
            else {
                pretty += jsonData[key] + "\n";
            }

        }
    }
    return pretty;
}



module.exports = {client: client, prettyPrint:prettyPrint};
```

created their CreateOrder:

```
/**
 * PayPal SDK dependency
 */
const checkoutNodeJssdk = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

/**
 * PayPal HTTP client dependency
 */
const payPalClient = require('./PayPalClient');

/**
 * Setting up the JSON request body for creating the Order. The Intent in the
 * request body should be set as "CAPTURE" for capture intent flow.
 *
 */
function buildRequestBody() {
    return {
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "application_context": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:8081/process",
            "cancel_url": "https://www.example.com",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "landing_page": "BILLING",
            "user_action": "CONTINUE"
        },
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "soft_descriptor": "Donation",
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "220.00"
                }
            }
        ]
    };
}

/**
 * This is the sample function which can be sued to create an order. It uses the
 * JSON body returned by buildRequestBody() to create an new Order.
 */
async function createOrder(debug=false) {
    try {
        const request = new checkoutNodeJssdk.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.headers["prefer"] = "return=representation";
        request.requestBody(buildRequestBody());
        const response = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
        if (debug){
            console.log("Status Code: " + response.statusCode);
            console.log("Status: " + response.result.status);
            console.log("Order ID: " + response.result.id);
            console.log("Intent: " + response.result.intent);
            console.log("Links: ");
            response.result.links.forEach((item, index) => {
                let rel = item.rel;
                let href = item.href;
                let method = item.method;
                let message = `\t${rel}: ${href}\tCall Type: ${method}`;
                console.log(message);
            });
            console.log(`Gross Amount: ${response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.currency_code} ${response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value}`);
            // To toggle print the whole body comment/uncomment the below line
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 4));
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

}

/**
 * This is the driver function which invokes the createOrder function to create
 * an sample order.
 */
if (require.main === module){
    (async() => await createOrder(true))();
}

/**
 * Exports the Create Order function. If needed this can be invoked from the
 * order modules to execute the end to flow like create order, retrieve, capture
 * and refund(Optional)
 */

module.exports = {createOrder:createOrder};
```

And endpoints:

```
const createUsersOrder = async (res) => {
    try {
        let response = await createOrder();
        console.log("Creating Order...");
        let orderId = "";
        if (response.statusCode === 201){
            console.log("Created Successfully");
            orderId = response.result.id;
            console.log("Links:");
            response.result.links.forEach((item, index) => {
                let rel = item.rel;
                let href = item.href;
                let method = item.method;
                let message = `\t${rel}: ${href}\tCall Type: ${method}`;
                console.log(message);
            });

            let links = {};
            response.result.links.forEach(function (linkObj) {
                links[linkObj.rel] = {
                    'href': linkObj.href,
                    'method': linkObj.method
                };
            })

            //if redirect url present, redirect user
            if (links.hasOwnProperty('approve')) {
                var returnObj = {redirect : links['approve'].href}
                console.log("Returning " + returnObj)
                res.send(returnObj);
            } else {
                console.error('no redirect URI present');
            }
        }

        console.log("Copy approve link and paste it in browser. Login with buyer account and follow the instructions.\nOnce approved hit enter...");
        return
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('There was an error: ', error);
    }
};

app.post("/create", function(req,res) {
    createUsersOrder(res);
})
```

Here, this is called when button is clicked, as "createOrder" method is called. I create order just like in the `v1` code, and then redirect browser to the url. However when the user approves transaction on paypal, and thus is being redirected to one of

```
"application_context": {
    "return_url": "http://localhost:8081/process",
    "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8081/cancel",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "landing_page": "BILLING",
    "user_action": "CONTINUE"
},
```

return url ( `/process` route for success ), the request DOES NOT contain `payment_id`, only `PAYER_ID`. But the `payment_id` ( or `order_id` in v2 ) is needed to capture the order.

Since i have found literally zero blogs, tutorials, guide for `v2` ( only millions for `v1`) i am confused where to get the order id. Do i really need to save it in DB after i create the order? OR is there any other trick?

Also, the button contains `onApprove` method, but after creating order, the browser is redirected to paypal, and the paypal redirects user to `http://localhost:8081/process` endpoint - thus the `onApprove` method is never invoked and useless (?).

This whole flow of  `v2` is really confusing, is there something i am missing?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your v2 code, do not use any redirects. At all. Your button should call 2 endpoints on your server. These two endpoints should (respectively) do the API operations of creating and capturing the order, and return the JSON result in each case (the capture route can do any server-side operations like storing the transaction result in the database before forwarding the JSON result to the client caller, since the client needs to handle any capture error situations as well as showing a success message). You can find a full stack node.js example in the [PayPal integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), but it's fine to keep your @paypal/react-paypal-js code pretty much as-is for the front end.

Comment: so in /create endpoint i should return only order_id ? How will i get the payer_id then?

Comment: You can return just an 'id' key or more simply return the whole object. For v2 you don't need a payer_id to capture. It'll be within the onApprove data anyway.

Comment: So the HATEOS links are there just for legacy code? Thats what confuses me the most as i did some stuff with v1 and it was heavily based on them. In other words i just need to return order_id from create, then capture the payment in onApprove

Comment: Correct, those links are for legacy sites that are not using the JS window for approval.

Comment: And now the node sdk has been archived  why paypal! 

Comment: Server-side SDKs are deprecated, yes. The standard guide has sample node code with no SDK.